# What is the most best method to isolate AirplaneMode per application?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, objective-c++, theos

I am building a preferences bundle tweak to enable users to 'fake' AirplaneMode per application/tweak.

I'm not sure what is the best method to call AirplaneMode without causing a global effect and I have researched the Internet, but anything like this hasn't been made yet.

I intend to use Applist to obtain the maximum amount of applications/processes for user management through the settings app.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: As I understand it, you want to disable internet access for specific apps, right? Both cell networking and Wi-Fi? You could just hook socket APIs to return error when an app tries to connect to something. Hooking lower level APIs will give you better coverege than, say, hooking NSStream like APIs. You never know what will be used. All apple networking APIs will use C APIs any way, so you might just hook them.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, yes I intended on restricting both frameworks, could you please specify which framework and header I should look into? Also, I am diverting from the 'apps' mindset, some tweaks run within the backend frameworks, others use preferenceloader... And so on.. So as you mentioned, I require a header at the lowest levels to provide a stable package, but which exactly? Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking BSD sockets would be enough. I don't know for sure but I think NSStream and CFSocket are based on them.